# Принцип постановки ударения

Tags: фонетика

Общеизвестно, что варенье из груш - грУшевое, из слив - слИвовое, из яблок - яблочное. Но при этом из айвы - айвОвое (хотя тут я могу предположить, что причина смещения ударения из-за краткости слова), но почему тогда из вишни варенье вишнёвое, а не вИшневое, как должно было быть по логике и по аналогии с грушевым и сливовым?
Откуда взялось это смещение ударения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно смещение ударения связывают с влиянием фонетических факторов. В частности, для относительных прилагательных с суффиксом ОВ анализируется подвижность ударения в мотивирующем существительном или считается, что ударение смещается к центру многосложного слова. Но иногда эти факторы идентичны, и тогда приходится задуматься о смысловом значении ударения. Позволю себе высказать свое собственное мнение, потому что материал на эту тему найти трудно.

Рассмотрим прилагательные с суффиксом ОВ/ЕВ, образованные от существительных "слива, яблоня, груша, вишня".

1. Ударение сохраняется на основе. В этом случае относительное прилагательное по смыслу тесно связано существительным: сливовый, яблоневый, грушевый (сад, варенье).
2. Ударение смещается на суффикс. Теперь в центе внимания относительная  связь: вишнёвый (есть не  только сад, варенье, но и ЦВЕТ вишни).
3. В некоторых прилагательных ударение падает на окончание, тогда подчеркивается признаковая способность прилагательного, которое служит опреДЕЛЕНИЕМ при классификации существительных: языкОвая колбаса, но языковЫе средства выразительности.

Для варианта айва - айвовый сохраняется ударение на втором слоге (как в существительном).

Answer (score 2):

А вы пробовали произнести "Айвовое". По-моему, это не очень удобно в артикуляции.